# How to include video chat in ios app?

Tags: ios, iphone, videochat

I'm just creating an app and I wanna include a video chat on it. I haven't seen before an app that uses video chats and I don't know if it's possible. Thanks.

Comment: very poor question, come back with a specific one

Comment: I wanna know if there's an API or framework that permits me to include a video chat in my app.

Comment: @user3288060, that's what Google is for. Stack overflow is for programming specific questions.

Comment: You haven't seen an app that does video chat? What about FaceTime? Or Skype?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may be able to use skype.  Hopefully [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn745885.aspx) link will help.